# Sort List<String[]> by order of Dates in Java

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a List of String arrays of the form

```
List<String[]> currentLoadAddressLocations = new ArrayList<>();
```

That gets set and parsed through a JSONObject Array

```
try {
            JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray dataObjArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("stops");
            Log.i(TAG, dataObjArray.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < dataObjArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject addressAndLocation = dataObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
            addressGPointJSON.add(addressAndLocation.getString("address"));
            locationGPointJSON.add(addressAndLocation.getString("location"));
            cityGPointJSON.add(addressAndLocation.getString("city"));
            stateGPointJSON.add(addressAndLocation.getString("state"));
            fromGPointJSON.add(addressAndLocation.getString("from"));
            latGPointJSON.add(reverseGeocoderLatLong(addressGPointJSON.get(i) + ", " + cityGPointJSON.get(i) + ", " + stateGPointJSON.get(0), true));
            longGPointJSON.add(reverseGeocoderLatLong(addressGPointJSON.get(i) + ", " + cityGPointJSON.get(i) + ", " + stateGPointJSON.get(0), false));

            currentLoadAddressLocations.add(i,
                    new String[]{
                            fromGPointJSON.get(i),
                            addressGPointJSON.get(i),
                            locationGPointJSON.get(i),
                            cityGPointJSON.get(i),
                            stateGPointJSON.get(i),
                            latGPointJSON.get(i),
                            longGPointJSON.get(i)
                    });
        } // end of for loop
        } // end of try catch block
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Currently, the code gives me back the data structure that I need, a String[] of the form

```
["2017-03-30 21:00:00", "Address example 123", "Location Example", "CITY", "STATE", "lat", "long"]
```

repeated depending on how many stops where in the JSON object that was returned. I need to find a way to sort the first value of the array from top to bottom inside the currentLoadAddressLocations array by time, so if one of the dates is "2017-03-30 15:00:00" and the other is "2017-03-30 14:00:00" then the one that is before takes precedence and moves the date to the top of the currenLoadAddressLocations array while at the same time araging the second one to be below. I am having a hard time trying to find a method of doing so. Currently I know that I can compare dates if I parse the dates as:

```
Date from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse("2017-03-30 21:00:00");
```

But do not know how to work around this issue while looping through the currentLoadAddressLocations List. Further more, I do not know how to access the values in order to compare them. I can loop through the selection by using

```
for(String[] array: currentLoadAddressLocations){
            for(String s: array){
                Log.i(TAG,"ITEM: " +  s);
            }
        }
```

But since they are inside a String array they cannot be changed into a date format unless I change them and then parse them back to strings.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you should convert your String[] into a AddressDateLocation class array. Once you do that, it will be much easier to sort you data the way you want

```
public class AddressDateLocation implements Comparable<AddressDateLocation> {
  Date date;
  String address;
  String location;

  public void setDate(Date d) {}
  public Date getDate() ...
  public void setLocation(String loc) ...
  public String getLocation() ...
  public void setAddress(String addr) ...
  public String getDate() ...

  public int compareTo(AddressDateLocation other) ...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about something similar to this but could not figure out how to properly introduce the compareTo method override as well as the how to use it, this does seem like the most sound idea. Could you provide me a suggestion as to how would I set the compareTo method? I greatly appreciate the answer oh great backyard suspension bridge builder!

Comment: Just do some research. The Comparable interface is explained a zillion times out there. There are countless examples how to do that.

Comment: Got it, it took less than I thought actually. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The *data structure you need* is likely not an array of String's, unless the order of the pieces ends up in a public API. You'd better keep the information in the native `JSONObject`, that has `Map` semantics. Then you can simply order by timestamp with:

```
List<JSONObject> currentLoadAddressLocations = TODO(/* implement this */);
currentLoadAddressLocations.sort((o1, o2) -> { 
    return o1.getString("date").compareTo(o2.getString("date"))
});
```

Note: the date format suggested in the question makes it possible to compare timestamps using their textual representation.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the dates into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects and use the compareTo method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [List#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) function like so:

```
currentLoadAddressLocations.sort((sa1, sa2) -> { // sa = String Array
    try {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US).parse(sa1[0])
                .compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US).parse(sa2[0]));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // If your dates are all valid you shouldn't come here.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1; // move all parse ParseExceptions to the first positions
    }
});
```

Comment: This is gold. Thank you Johan, I am not in the process of compare options to see which answer works best for me, your example works flawlesly albeit I had to make some minor changes because my Android project is not supporting lambda at this time. It still works perfeclty!!

Comment: Keep in mind that the exception is not really handled though. Only the stack trace is printed and the faults are moved to the first positions of the list. If you're 100% sure that the string is parse-able than it shouldn't be a real problem. Otherwise you have to find a way to handle the exception correctly.

Comment: I figured as much, it is coming directly from our API in question so I am quite positive that it will stay like that for the foreseeable future. Thanks for the warning! You are the bomb!